# Passing SQLite query results to html page

Tags: javascript, ajax, sqlite

```
$ResultLine = $db->query("SELECT customerid FROM mydb WHERE surname= Holmes ORDER BY customerid DESC LIMIT 10")->fetchArray();
$res = $ResultLine[0];
echo json_encode($res);
```

Let's say there are 3 customers with the same surname in the database and different customerid. How can I structure the code above to return all the pairs customerid/surname as an array to my html page? The code above obviously only returns one customerid.

Comment: Without knowing what `$db->query` returns it's hard to answer. btw I presume `Holmes` in your query is actually a parameter/enclosed in quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `fetchArray()` returns one row at a time. So this snippet gets the first row and sends the first element ([0]) to json_encode. Remove `->fetchArray()` from the set statement, then iterate over $ResultLine, something like:

```
while ($row = $ResultLine->fetchArray()) {

     //do something with $row values
}
```

Doc found [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlite3result.fetcharray.php)